# Cargar un usuario de un select, con petición ajax y archivo local jason

Tags: php, ajax, json

En el select list con el id=”slc-usuario” agregar la funcionalidad para que al cambiar de usuario se obtenga los detalles del
usuario como nombre completo, imagen, etc. Leer la información del archivo /data/usuarios.json

mi codigo HTML

```
<div class="component text-center">
  <select class="form-control" id="slc-usuario">
    <option value="@patricio">Patricio</option>
    <option value="@dende">Dende</option>
    <option value="@goku">Goku</option>
    <option value="@vegeta">Vegeta</option>
    <option value="@bulma">Bulma</option>
  </select>
  <div class="component-header">
    <img src="img/profile-pics/patricio.jpg"
      class="img-fluid rounded-circle img-thumbnail">
  </div>
  <hr>
  <h2 class="blue-text">Patricio Perez</h2>
  <small>@patricio</small>
  <hr>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      Tweets<br>
      <span class="blue-text">5</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      Following<br>
      <span class="blue-text">4</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      Followers<br>
      <span class="blue-text">3</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Json con los usuarios:

```
{"usuario":"@goku","nombre":"Goku","apellido":"Rodriguez","urlImagen":"img/profile-pics/goku.jpg","tweets":"5","followers":"3","following":"4"}

{"usuario":"@vegeta","nombre":"Vegeta","apellido":"Lainez","urlImagen":"img/profile-pics/vegeta.jpg","tweets":"5","followers":"3","following":"4"}

{"usuario":"@bulma","nombre":"Bulma","apellido":"Gomez","urlImagen":"img/profile-pics/bulma.jpg","tweets":"5","followers":"3","following":"4"}
```

mi controlador:

```
$("#slc-usuario").change(function(){
  // Esta funcion se ejecuta cada vez que el usuario selecciona
  // o cambia un elemento de la lista.
  console.log("Usuario seleccionado: " + $("#slc-usuario").val());
  alert("(COMENTAR ESTE ALERT). Debe hacer una petición AJAX para obtener los detalles del usuario para cambiar la fotografía y el nombre mostrados.");
});
```

Comment: Bienvenido. Nos gustaría saber qué problemas estás teniendo con tu código. Puedes editar la pregunta para añadir más información y así poder ayudarte.

Comment: Ya le agregue amigo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Necesitas hacer una función AJAX parecida a esta:

```
var user = $("#slc-usuario").val());
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "tu_archivo.php",
        data: {"user" : user},
        success:function(data){
                var data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(error){
                console.log(error);
        }
    });
```

En el archivo PHP (tu_archivo.php) procesas los datos de la variable $_REQUEST, en donde encontrarás $_REQUEST['user'] con el nombre de usuario seleccionado.
Con ese dato debe generar la respuesta de que JSON será devuelto y, finalmente, enviarlo de regreso a la función AJAX por medio de:

```
return json_encode($myJSON);
```

Así el JSON se convertirá en "data" de la función "success". Luego lo parseas y ya podrás usar toda la información del JSON.